# при попытке назначения переменной bot значения commands.bot(префикс) в discord.py вылетает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

[image: вот и сама ошибка]

это сама ошибка
пытался решить тем что писал префикс напрямую не помогло

как такое можно исправить ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В тексте ошибки указано, что не заполнен обязательный параметр `intents`. Как исправить - заполнить его.

Comment: @insolor спасибо за ответ но я это понимаю только у меня не хватает мозгов как его заполнить

Comment: Читайте документацию по боту, смотрите примеры.

Comment: @insolor окей спасибо ...

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь, в  новой версии `discord py`, нужно обязательно указывать `intents` при создании бота.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
my_bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix', intents=intents)
```

intents это, грубо говоря, то, что будет отслеживать бот (т.е на какие события он подписан и какие данные он будет кэшировать)

Из [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

> The intents that are necessary for your bot can only be dictated by yourself. Each attribute in the Intents class documents what events it corresponds to and what kind of cache it enables.

> Намерения, которые необходимы для вашего бота, можете диктовать только вы сами. Каждый атрибут в классе Intents документирует, каким событиям он соответствует и какой тип кэша он включает.